# Vertical GridSplitter not resizable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a GridSplitter which can resize rows in a Grid. The Grid is made of three rows, each one has a StackPanel which contains two labels (name, surname, age):

```
<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="5" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Rows"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
        <Label FontSize="25" Margin="10">Name</Label>
        <Label x:Name="nameLabel" FontSize="25" Margin="10"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
        <Label FontSize="25" Margin="10">Surname</Label>
        <Label x:Name="surnameLabel" FontSize="25" Margin="10"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">
        <Label FontSize="25" Margin="10">Age</Label>
        <Label x:Name="ageLabel" FontSize="25" Margin="10"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

With this code the first row isn't resizable. I see the GridSplitter, and I also see the arrow when I pass the mouse over it, but if I drag it the row doesn't get resized.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually place the `GridSplitter` in its own `GridRow`. This will give you the desired effect:

```
<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
        <Label FontSize="25" Margin="10">Name</Label>
        <Label x:Name="nameLabel" FontSize="25" Margin="10"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="5"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">
        <Label FontSize="25" Margin="10">Surname</Label>
        <Label x:Name="surnameLabel" FontSize="25" Margin="10"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3">
        <Label FontSize="25" Margin="10">Age</Label>
        <Label x:Name="ageLabel" FontSize="25" Margin="10"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That is indeed the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `GridSplitter`'s `VerticalAlignment` to `"Bottom"`